# How does Yukihira Soma get into Totsuki Culinary Academy?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

On season 1 episode 2, it is quite clear that Nakiri Erina rejects Somas application and says nobody passed the transfer exam.

I'm aware of the single shot which shows the director hanging in the background, but he didn't taste the food nor is it clear that he issued the invitation to Soma.

So how does Soma get invited to Totsuki?

Comment: My guess is that he may have seen/heard either directly or from other sources the recipe that soma cooked and Erina tastes it.. also keep in mind he always has eye on soma.. probably he might know soma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 4 of the manga, when Nakiri is toeing off against Souma after the welcoming ceremonies and we see the headmaster watching them, we get the following flashback page:

[image: he eats Souma's dish after Nakiri leaves and loves it]

Answer (score 0):

In the very same episode (or in the manga, I forget which), it was shown that the director did tasted Soma's cookings. He probably (I 95% believe it was him considering the situations) was the one that overriden Nakiri Erina's decision.

Comment: In the anime, afaik, after Erina is fuming about how did Souma get in Totsuki, it is shown that the director was listening outside smiling, indicating he stepped in to make sure Souma got it. Souma, as usual is clueless. Not sure about the Manga though

Answer (score 0):

It's shown in the anime... After the credits I believe. There is always something after the credits of each episode and I'm not talking about just the preview for the next episode.